Publishing a new crate
I cloned the solana repo and made a new crate that is an exact clone of solana-client just to learn how to publish a new crate. I renamed it and when I try to publish it I am getting
error: failed to verify package tarball
Caused by:
failed to select a version for the requirement solana_rbpf = "=0.8.1"
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.8.5, 0.8.4, 0.8.3, ...
location searched: crates.io index
required by package solana-program-runtime v2.0.0
... which satisfies dependency solana-program-runtime = "=2.0.0" of package solana-vote-program v2.0.0
... which satisfies dependency solana-vote-program = "=2.0.0" of package solana-rpc-client v2.0.0
... which satisfies dependency solana-rpc-client = "=2.0.0" of package solana-client-test v2.0.0 (~/projects/solana/target/package/solana-client-test-2.0.0)
perhaps a crate was updated and forgotten to be re-vendored?
I am confused because it uses all of the same versions as the actual solana-client, so I am trying to understand how this works. solana_rbpf 0.8.1 was yanked which explains why this error appears but if that's the case how are any changes to solana-client ever published, I would imagine you would see the same error?
Thanks!

You'll need to provide some more info... likely you're using some other dependency that's requiring something higher than 0.8.1 of solana_rbpf. Even though the crate was yanked, it can still be used as normal, it just gets skipped over during default resolution. As a quick fix, try using something higher than v2.0.0 of the solana crates, like v2.0.13. That might resolve the issue you're seeing. Otherwise, you'll need to provide your full Cargo.toml
